# HTML Mosaic - coding possibilities

Tags: javascript, html, css, mosaic

I have to program a big picture mosaic on webpage, and I'm wondering what is best approach to code it, so the solution would be not very complicated to program and to maintain/change it later.

Here is a design for mosaic, each picture may change, both black and white and colour.

[image: Mosaic]

I was thinking about 3 different approaches:

1. `<table>` solution,
2. `<div>` and each div has its `position:absolute` set in CSS,
3. `<div>` and placing with JS ( array with positions/ sizes ).

Any other ideas ?

Comment: Have you come across masonry?  http://masonry.desandro.com/  Looks like it might help you achieve that type of layout.  Also Isotope is another JS alternative http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: I don't think that table is the way to go.

Comment: Just one think to add :-) mosaic is just first step, after I do mosaic skeleton, I have to add a lot of different code around ( CMS + my custom Javascript photo editor etc. )

Comment: Anyone else thought someone was trying to make a webpage work in the Mosiac browser? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this page here](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/05/pinterest-style-box-layout/)? I can imagine it would be easy to do your skeleton and your further plans with those explanations. :-)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Great to see you're helping out, next time, try to anticipate more to the question. In this case, specify what approach of the 3 suggested in the question is taken in your case?

Comment: Ha! First answer and i forgot half of the stuff. Sorry! The creator of the page i linked did something with divs and javascript, so it goes in direction of suggestion three. I don't know about the plans after doing the skeleton for the mosaic, but i think this would be the best way to do it if the user who asked just want to use html, css and js.